# How to create semi circle with tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-3

I am trying to create a semicircle with a tailwind but I can't seem to find another way but this one.

```
<div className="relative  ">
  <div className="bg-black h-36 w-36 rounded-full absolute top-[50px] left-[555px] "></div>
  <div className="bg-white h-24 w-36 absolute top-[110px] left-[555px]   "></div>
</div>
```

is there any better way u know cuz this feels a little off, I feel like there are other better ways to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to do so using `rounded-tr` and `rounded-tl`
here is what You need to do:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="relative flex justify-center items-center h-screen w-screen">

<div class="h-12 w-24 bg-indigo-500 
            rounded-tl-full rounded-tr-full "></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow Thanks mate, this is literally what I was looking for,, Thanks

Comment: @AbelKibebe , glad to help! happy coding.